Recover my original azure system generated username and password
I created a free Azure account recently for my practice sessions.
The username and passwords were system generated and I didn't save them anywhere.
During my practice sessions, I invited a guest account. I logged in using the guest account and realised I cannot do any admin task on the azure. Therefore I wanted to go back and login with the system generated account. Unfortunately I didn't save these credentials initially. Now it appears I cannot recover my account. Is there a way to recover my account
I invited a guest account and wanted to test if the guest account would managed admin tasks on the azure account

Welcome to SO. This question doesn't really relate to programming or software development, so is a little off-topic for this forum. That said, you may have to log an azure support ticket. But it sounds like you might not have much information to offer to try and locate the account.
